# VPN vs SSH tunnelling for hotel wifi

Tags: vpn, ssh, tunneling

I know it's recommended to use a VPN with a hotel WiFi but if I'm in a hurry and don't have time to setup my own VPN server would an SSH tunnel (invoked with `ssh -D`) work just as well to secure my web traffic?

Comment: Also look into `sshuttle` https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an SSH tunnel will provide the same confidentiality and integrity as an OpenVPN or IPSec VPN tunnel, assuming the configuration is secure. If you expect an active MITM attack, you will need to [verify](https://superuser.com/q/1246732/893950) that the SSH fingerprint that you are seeing is correct. If you have set up the server, you should take a note of the fingerprint so you can verify that it is correct when you connect to the server.

Note that SSH uses TCP, and [TCP-over-TCP](http://sites.inka.de/%7EW1011/devel/tcp-tcp.html) is not recommended due to performance issues. It's fine if you're in a hurry, but UDP is a better protocol to encapsulate TCP than TCP is.